# Fullcalendar events not displaying in horizontal resource week view

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I need to make a view that display events for a whole week but horizontaly like [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yiQPF.png). It was hard finding documentation and advice for making each day verticaly and the slot duration horizontaly but i found [here](https://codepen.io/acerix/pen/MWbWBJZ?editors=0011) an exemple using resources as day slots. My issue is that i have created 6 events for different day of my week but only those of the current day is displaying. However if I change the initial day of my view it will display the event of this day. The view used is `initialView: 'resourceTimelineDay',` but in the example we could create more events and it displays them even if they were from a different day so i don't understand why not on mine. here is my code if someone can help me.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
      var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

      var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
        editable: true,
        initialView: 'resourceTimelineDay',
        locale: 'fr',
        timeZone: 'UTC',     
        height: 'auto',
        dateIncrement: {weeks: 1},

        customButtons: {
          prev: {
            text: 'Prev',
            click: function() {
              var weekday = getFirstDayOfWeek(currentDateOfWeek,"Monday");
              currentDateOfWeek.setUTCDate( weekday.getUTCDate() -7);
              calendar.prev(); 
            }
          },
          next: {
            text: 'Next',
            click: function() {  
              var weekday = getLastDayOfWeek(currentDateOfWeek,"Monday");
              currentDateOfWeek.setUTCDate(weekday.getUTCDate() + 7);
              calendar.next();     
            }
          },
        },

        eventDataTransform: function(data) {
          data.resourceId = data.start.substr(0, 10)
          console.log(data);
          return data
        },

        events: [
          {
            title: 'Test1',
            start: '2023-02-27T08:00:00',
            end: '2023-02-27T10:00:00'
          },
          {
            title: 'Test2',
            start: '2023-02-28T08:00:00',
            end: '2023-02-28T15:00:00'
          },
          {
            title: 'Test3',
            start: '2023-03-01T05:00:00',
            end: '2023-03-01T11:00:00',
          },
          {
            title: 'Test4',
            start: '2023-03-02T01:00:00',
            end: '2023-03-02T05:00:00',
          },
          {
            title: 'Test5',
            start: '2023-03-02T12:00:00',
            end: '2023-03-02T16:00:00',
          },
          {
            title: 'Test6',
            start: '2023-03-03T09:00:00',
            end: '2023-03-03T10:00:00',
          },
        ],
        
        refetchResourcesOnNavigate: true,
        resources: function(fetchInfo, successCallback, failureCallback) {
          var curr = new Date(currentDateOfWeek); 
          var firstday = getFirstDayOfWeek(curr, "Monday");
          var lastday = getLastDayOfWeek(curr, "Monday");

          var resources = []
          getDates(firstday, lastday).forEach(function(date) {
            var options = {weekday: "long",  day: "numeric"};
            resources.push({
              id: date.toISOString().substr(0, 10),
              title: date.toLocaleString("fr-FR", options)
            })
          })
          successCallback(resources)
        }
      });

      calendar.render();
    });
```

Comment: Notice how the eventDataTransform in the CodePen link you provided sets the start date of every event to the first of the month? You've removed that bit in your version, but that's needed because, as far as fullCalendar's concerned, it's only displaying one day in the timeline, not all the ones that you've faked in your resources. So it won't show anything with a start date not on the day it thinks it's showing.

Comment: P.S. I'd just like to state, for the record, that I think this is a terrible idea and will cause you lots of headaches. Just use the timeGridWeek view - it's the same thing, but rotated 90 degrees. And it actually works. Put in a feature request to fullCalendar if you want to get a horizontal version of it, and/or work on your own custom view, would be my advice.

Comment: Thanks alot I will fix the missing part and try it out.